# Shiro/Stormpath via REST

Tags: shiro, stormpath

I'm new to Shiro. We are attempting to use Shiro with Stormpath. I've been trying to dissect the examples to come up with a solution to what I want to do, but I'm unsuccessful so far.

For now, I'm simply trying to create REST services to do what I want, and I'll tie a real client in later. This is what I'm trying to achieve as my first step:

I want to have a client hit a REST endpoint (login) on my server. My server would authenticate, and return a JWT to the client. This JWT would then be used to access secured endpoints on my server. (I have written Java code that can successfully authenticate against Stormpath).

My problem is the JWT. I expected that a JWT would be created for me, or at least easily accessible. I can't find a way to get one. I have seen sample code on how to build one, but that doesn't seem like the way I would expect to acquire one.

I have run through several examples, but most seem to deal with JSP interfaces, and I can't seem to make the leap to what I'm trying to do.

Is this approach reasonable? Any guidance is appreciated.

**Edit 1**

I now have a Java client that can authenticate using the Shiro servlet and retrieve a JWT. I have this running as a deployed application (war) in GlassFish. My next step is to use that JWT to authenticate against a *different* application that has my REST endpoints. This REST application doesn't need to know anything about how to authenticate - I just want to pass the JWT along in the call to a given REST endpoint and use Shiro (via annotations) to control access to the endpoint (if that is indeed possible). All of the examples I can find seem to be "all-in-one" examples (bundling JSP with Shiro/Stormpath configurations, etc). I'm trying to determine the minimum working configuration for securing REST endpoints and I'm having difficulty determining which pieces of the configuration I need.

**Edit 2**

I am using the Stormpath-Shiro-Servlet (as stolen from the Shiro Servlet example) as my authentication back-end. Using my Java client, I am sending a login request to the servlet, and I am indeed getting back a JWT. However, I am not able to successfully use the JWT to access my other rest resources. My rest calls result in this error:

`org.apache.shiro.authz.UnauthenticatedException: This subject is anonymous - it does not have any identifying principals and authorization operations require an identity to check against.  A Subject instance will acquire these identifying principals automatically after a successful login is performed be executing org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject.login(AuthenticationToken) or when 'Remember Me' functionality is enabled by the SecurityManager.  This exception can also occur when a previously logged-in Subject has logged out which makes it anonymous again.  Because an identity is currently not known due to any of these conditions, authorization is denied.`

First, I don't understand why the servlet 'login' doesn't actually log me in and give me non-anonymous principle? Second, I am attempting to do everything on a separate client, so I don't have access to Subject.login (is this a correct assumption?).

Comment: What does your request look like over the wire?  Can you capture it and post it here (censoring when needed)?

Comment: I'm stuck again. I'm hitting the servlet at both /login and /oath/token. I get a response back, and it looks fine in the sense that my Stormpath account URI is correct. I'm assuming this means my configuration is correct because the account URI must be being returned from the Stormpath server. But I don't see any groups or claims. I've inspected the JWT with JWT debugger and the JWT Analyzer and Inspector. I have `stormpath.web.oauth2.authorizer.secure.resolver = com.stormpath.sdk.servlet.config.SecureResolverFactory` configured if that is a factor.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-shiro/tree/ecb2edf45c24fa59a2316fbbdbddd47f46a7c57f/examples/servlet) from [github/stormpath-shiro](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-shiro)

The JWT creation is managed for you by the Stormpath API. If you start up one of the examples, (the servlet one above, or the spring-boot-web example), after login, you will have a JWT cookie.  There is background info in [this blog post](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-for-java).

I'm working on releasing strompath-shiro now, but figured I'd include these link here so you can start looking.

Comment: I have seen both - the blog post was one of the reasons I thought I might have to "roll my own" JWT solution. With regard to the example, I've also tried to get it working, without success. I'm getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's configuration does not have a stormpath.application.href property defined. ` I have set environment variables, set variables in Maven/Jetty, tried to add a stormpath.properties file, but no success.

Comment: After much debugging, I've found the only way to make the example application work is to have only one application in Stormpath other than the default "Stormpath" application.

Comment: @ben_979 That might be a bug. Specifying the application `href` should allow you to select one application out of many. Can you report it on github/stormpath-shiro?

Comment: @ben_979, it was a bug on the dev branch, it has been fixed.