# Correct configuration for REST endpoints in Shiro

Tags: shiro

My original post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381112/shiro-stormpath-via-rest)

I am trying to protect a set of REST endpoints with Shiro. My theory is that if I pass a JWT with my REST request, that I can use Shiro (via annotations) to secure my endpoints.

I've create my endpoints like this (for example):

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("status/{companyId}")
@RequiresAuthentication
@RequiresRoles("SomeRole")
public Response getStatus(@PathParam("companyId") int companyId){
  ... do stuff ...
}
```

I'm expecting that if I call the endpoint without authenticating, I will get a HTTP 401 error. However, the method is called successfully if the JWT is not supplied *as it would be when there is no security on it at all*.

I assume then that my Shiro config is incorrect. Since this is strictly a 'backend' application, I have no use for the Shiro/Stormpath configurations that apply to anything 'front-end' related (such as loginURLs, etc.)

Here is my shiro.ini :

```
[main]
#ERRORS IF UNCOMMENTED
#cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
#securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager
#stormpathClient.cacheManager = $cacheManager

# NOT NEEDED?
#sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
#securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
#securityManager.sessionManager.sessionIdCookieEnabled = false
#securityManager.sessionManager.sessionIdUrlRewritingEnabled = false

[urls]
/** = rest
```

This configuration lets every request through (as described above).

If I uncomment the [main] section, I get `IllegalArgumentException: Configuration error.  Specified object [stormpathClient] with property [cacheManager] without first defining that object's class.  Please first specify the class property first, e.g. myObject = fully_qualified_class_name and then define additional properties.`

What I need to figure out is what is the correct minimum Shiro configuration for REST endpoints (and ONLY REST endpoints) so I can allow access with a JWT.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the annotations are not being processed by anything at runtime. You will need to tell your JAX-RS app to process them.

I've done this with this lib in the past:
https://github.com/silb/shiro-jersey/

Specifically something like this:
https://github.com/silb/shiro-jersey/blob/master/src/main/java/org/secnod/shiro/jersey/AuthorizationFilterFeature.java

As for the second part of the problem, my only guess is Stormpath/Shiro environment is not setup correctly.

Did you put filter config in your web.xml or is all of the config loaded from the servlet fragment?